# Compiling FFMpeg for windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I'm interested in having the libfdk_aac library in ffmpeg. I followed the guide for compiling ffmpeg from this site:

`https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite`

The end result is a big directory with multiple files. I found the ffmpeg.exe under bin-video (I guess I might be choosing the wrong options?). The exe works but it needs some dll files created by the build. As far as I know, other ffmpeg.exe versions I have are the single file. I have a version from MCEBuddy that includes the libfdk_aac library I'm interested in and it's a single file. How can I compile the program and have a single ffmpeg file as a result?

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar process and came upon vcpkg. This is a package manager that essentially automates the download and build process.

1. Install vcpkg - https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html
   I did this in a separate HDD.

Step 1: Clone the vcpkg repo.
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
Step 2: Run the bootstrap script to build vcpkg.
.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

2. Install your lib.

.\vcpkg install ffmpeg

3. If using Visual Studio, add the vcpkg installs to all your projects.

.\vcpkg integrate install

If you just need the libs, they are available under vcpkg\buildtrees

Once you get started, you will find other GitHub libs you will need, and I have found all my requirements with vcpkg. Its a bonus if you use visual studio, as all your libs are automatically available in your projects.

Conan is another package manager you may consider.